# call request.querystring inside javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

how to call Request.QueryString inside javascript function and i am using asp.net and C#

```
var str=<%=Request.quesryString("val")%>
```

but it is giving me error

Answer (score 8):

If this javascript code is inline in your webform the correct way is to use a [`javascript serializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Request.QueryString["val"]) %>;
    alert(str);
</script>
```

**Never** do the following, it's completely unsafe and your site vulnerable to XSS injection attacks:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = '<%= Request.QueryString["val"] %>';
    alert(str);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with JavaScript directly.

With `window.location.search` you get full queryString like  `?item1=val1&item2=val2`

You can get querystring using some like

> window.location.search.substr(1)

and use `.split('&')` or *substring* function to get value of de 'val' key or another

Answer (score 1):

You can actually write a function in javascript and pass the query string as parameter from the code behind.
For example I have this textbox I want to set the value to the query

```
function searchTerm(text) {
        document.getElementById('txtSearch').value = text;
}
```

So in my code I use ScriptManager to call the javascript function and pass the query that way

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "", "searchTerm('" + Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() + "')", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging the theme of security in requests in ASP NET...

You can also use [JavaScriptStringEncode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode.aspx) or the [AntiXSS library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814) to prevent XSS in your website.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong use this code to get the QueryString value because it isn't just giving you a Query String in JavaScript it will convert this into an object so use $.each function to retrieve the value of Query String

```
 let id = $(<%= Request.QueryString["id"] %>);
                    id.each((index, value) => {
                        console.log(value);
                    })
```

It will return you a value of your Query String
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this:

> var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
>
> console.log(urlParams.has('someValue')); // true
>
> console.log(urlParams.get('someValue')); // "value"

it's key sensitive

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: You can't. The code in the `<%= %>` block is evaluated on the server side, the JavaScript code is evaluated on the client side.

Long answer: You CAN use inline C# code to generate JavaScript code, which sometimes does make sense. But this is not the same thing as calling C# code from a JavaScipt function. Of course you can only do this in .aspx / .cshtml etc. files, not in .js files, because those are only treated as content and not parsed by ASP.NET.

[EDIT] In your situation there is no need to bother anyway, because you can get the query string through JS anyway, see [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

[EDIT2]: Of course the other answer about the JavaScriptSerializer is absoultely correct concerning safety. If you use the Razor view engine, things get a lot easier and safer because it escapes strings by default. But like I said, in the concrete case, there's no need to bother either way.

Comment: Whilst you are correct, `QueryString` is perfectly callable on the client side. Regardless of whether it's executed on server or client, the call will produce the same (and desired) result.

Comment: @mattytommo you are misleading in saying that QueryString is perfectly callable on the client side.  It's a server function.  The results from such a server function call may be passes to the client in the form of a generated piece of javascript, as this answer states.

Comment: @ManishMishra: I didn't say it was a good idea in the concrete case. See edit for clarification.

Comment: @James: Correct, but you CAN get the query string with pure JS with no need to inject dynamically generated JS code through ASP.NET.

Comment: @James: No, that's not what he said. He (quite correctly) said that not properly escaping dynamically generated JS code is dangerous. I was talking about not using server-generated JS at all.

Comment: @chris you're right I didn't think it through, as long as eval isn't involved it's safe to use window.location.search et al.